# Celery worker not processing the task if previous task took more than 5000 seconds

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, celery, python-3.5, celery-task

I am using celery to execute sql statements usng sqlalchemy. I have one dedicated worker to perform this activity.I have set concurrency level to 1 as I want to execute all my statements sequentially. Few of the statements run for 5-6 hours. When any task ran for more than 4900-5000 seconds,my next task not get processed by the worker even if that worker is free. My send_task() returns task id to me with state pending,but worker not picking that task.
My celery settings are

```
app = Celery('tasks', broker=config.AGENT_BROKER,
         backend=config.AGENT_BACKEND, include=['tasks'],
         task_serializer='json')
```

My celery start command is

```
celery -A tasks worker -c 1 -Q executesql -P eventlet
```

Please help